# How to have a thread/process always active and request the updated value of one of its variables every certain time interval in another thread/process

Tags: python, multithreading, process, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

import multiprocessing
import time
import random

finish_state = multiprocessing.Event()

#function that requests frames
def actions_func(frame):
    while True:
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
        cv2.imshow('requested_frame_1',frame)

        time.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
        cv2.imshow('requested_frame_2',frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break

#function that keeps the camera always on and should return the frame value with the last image only when requested
def capture_cam():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

    if (cap.isOpened() == False): 
        print("Unable to read camera feed")

    # Default resolutions of the frame are obtained. The default resolutions are system dependent.
    # We convert the resolutions from float to integer.
    frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cap.get(4))


    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret == True: 
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break

        else:
            break  


def main_process(finish_state):

    thr1, frame = multiprocessing.Process(target=capture_cam)
    thr1.start()

    thr2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=actions_func, args=(frame,))
    thr2.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_process(finish_state)

print("continue the code with other things after all threads/processes except the main one were closed with the loop that started them... ")
```

I want a webcam to be open all the time capturing an image, for this I have created thread1 where it is supposed to run all the time regardless of the program.
What you need is to fix this program that is supposed to ask for frames from the function that always runs on thread1.
The problem is that I don't know when it might be time to ask thread1 for the last frame it showed, and to represent that I put the `random.randint(1,5)`, although in reality I won't have knowledge of the maximum or minimum time in which the last frame will be requested from thread1

The truth is that I'm getting complicated with this program, and I really don't know if it's convenient to create a thread2 to do the frame requests or if it's better to just have thread1 and have the frame requests inside the main thread

Although they say thread they are actually parallel processes, try with threads but I think it is more convenient to use processes, right?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "request_frames_thread.py", line 58, in <module>
    main_process(finish_state)
  File "request_frames_thread.py", line 50, in main_process
    thr1, frame = multiprocessing.Process(target=capture_cam)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Process object
```

Comment: I don't understand when you say "they" and "you". Do you want one thread to call `cap.read()` continuously and signal the other when it has a new image? The error you get is because you try to assign the `Process` object returned by `multiprocessing.Process` to two variables.

Comment: Sorry, I was using the translator, there may be mistakes in my English. As for the code, I need 2 process/threads, one that keeps the webcam on ```capture_cam()``` in a ```while True:``` loop that constantly updates the ```frame``` variable with the data from the last catch. And I need another thread/process ```actions_func(frame)``` that does some operations with the images that are saved in the variable ```frame``` which should be receiving from the first thread ```capture_cam()``` at specific moments.

Comment: I don't know the exact times when the thread/process where the ```actions_func(frame)``` function is executed should request the data from the updated ```frame``` variable, so to simplify the question I symbolized those unknown times with ```time.sleep(random number)```

Comment: You have your first call to `multiprocessing.Process` returning a tuple, the second element of which is a frame that you pass to the creation of the second `multiprocessing.Process`. But the `multiprocessing.Process()` call only returns a `Process` instance and not a frame.  So I really don't understand what you think these functions are doing and how they do it yet you want to know whether multithreading or multiprocessing is more appropriate. There are not enough details to answer that. Your program as posted does not make any sense and is not a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: @Booboo Hello, excuse me, in the code that I put, the initialization of the 2 processes is done, what I am asking here is how to send a variable called ```frame``` that is in one of the processes to the other process where it will be used. The problem I'm having is that while I can start the processes, what I can't do is the second process can get the updated  ```frame``` from the first process.

Comment: You showed an exception stack trace and I am simply trying to tell you the cause of it. You have in effect asked implicitly three (3) questions without realizing it: (1) How to pass the updated frame? (2) Should I use multiprocessing or multithreading? (3) Why am I getting this stack trace? **So now we will concentrate on question number 1 since I  have answered number 3 and number 2 cannot be answered on what you have provided.**

Comment: @Booboo The question I really need is the one you call **question 1**, and it's how to communicate the `frame` variable from one process to another. Regarding **question 2**, using processes is something that I read in the documentation but I didn't quite understand, anyway, since I don't know how to communicate in real time the `frame` variable from one process to the other without either of them ending , I really don't know if it's better to go for threads or processes. **But the problem in short, how to send the updated `frame` variable from one thread to the other without either ending?**

Comment: `capture_cam` probably needs to be a process since threads do not really run in parallel if they are executing Python bytecode since they lock on the Global Interpreter Lock. Threads are okay if they are mostly doing I/O or waiting on network activity to complete because they do not need the GIL for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have the main process create a full duplex [`multiprocessing.Pipe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pipe#multiprocessing.Pipe) instance which returns two  `multiprocessing.connection.Connection` instances and pass one connection to each of your processes. These connections can be used for a simple two way communication vehicle for sending and receiving objects to one another. I would have the `capture_cam` process start a *dameon* thread (it will terminate when all your *regular* threads terminate and so it can be in an infinite loop) that is passed on of these connections to handle requests for the latest frame, which is stored in a global variable.

The only requirement is that a frame be serializable by the `pickle` module.

```py
import multiprocessing
from threading import Thread
import time
import random


#function that requests frames
def actions_func(conn):
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
            # Ask for latest frame by sending any message:
            conn.send('frame')
            frame = conn.recv() # This is the response
             cv2.imshow('requested_frame_1',frame)

            time.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
            # Ask for latest frame by sending any message:
            conn.send('frame')
            frame = conn.recv() # This is the response
            cv2.imshow('requested_frame_2',frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break
    except BrokenPipeError:
        # The capture_cam process has terminated.
        pass

def handle_frame_requests(conn):
    try:
        while True:
            # Any message coming in is a request for the latest frame:
            request = conn.recv()
            conn.send(frame) # The frame must be pickle-able
    except EOFError:
        # The actions_func process has ended
        # and its connection has been closed.
        pass

#function that keeps the camera always on and should return the frame value with the last image only when requested
def capture_cam(conn):
    global frame

    frame = None

    # start dameon thread to handle frame requests:
    Thread(target=handle_frame_requests, args=(conn,), daemon=True).start()

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

    if (cap.isOpened() == False):
        print("Unable to read camera feed")

    # Default resolutions of the frame are obtained. The default resolutions are system dependent.
    # We convert the resolutions from float to integer.
    frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cap.get(4))


    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret == True:
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break

        else:
            break


def main_process(finish_state):
    conn1, conn2 = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=True)

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=capture_cam, args=(conn1,))
    p1.start()

    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=actions_func, args=(conn2,))
    p2.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    finish_state = multiprocessing.Event()
    main_process(finish_state)
```

Comment: The variable `frame` is an image in  `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`, and it could be serialized perfectly. Thank you very much for the help, especially for the explanation that helped me to clarify several doubts.

Comment: I have updated the answer so that if `capture_cam` terminates before `actions_func`, the former handles a possible exception of the connection.

Comment: really thanks again, you are right to put the exception in case there were any failures in the camera input function.